# android service call OnCreated unintentionally while running

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have strange problem. I have a service that start a thread, in that thread there is bluetooth connection. That works okay (it is still in development, but it works), I have encounter a strange problem: Here is a little LogCat dump, it should be stated that the service is running at this point.

```
09-17 14:11:07.154: D/ReadXmlService(4552): The maximum numbers of event on the watch is reach (max: 5)
09-17 14:11:07.154: D/MetaWatchReminderApp(4552): size of lastUpdatedEventsFromXml: 0
09-17 14:11:07.154: D/MetaWatchReminderApp(4552): size of compareList: 4
09-17 14:11:07.154: D/MetaWatchReminderApp(4552): compareList.tostring: [dk.detech.metawatchreminder.EventsInfo@ca23e0ae,     dk.detech.metawatchreminder.EventsInfo@3bc334bf, dk.detech.metawatchreminder.EventsInfo@93e2b014, dk.detech.metawatchreminder.EventsInfo@895bc157]
09-17 14:11:07.154: D/MetaWatchReminderApp(4552): lastUpdatedEventsFromXml.toString: []
09-17 14:11:07.154: D/MetaWatchReminderApp(4552): The list have been updated return true
09-17 14:11:07.154: D/ReadXmlService(4552): new items in lastUpdatedEventsFromXml
09-17 14:11:15.071: D/CalenderService(4552): onCreate'd
09-17 14:11:25.091: D/ApacheBackground(4552): Background task
09-17 14:11:25.091: D/ApacheBtService(4552): onCreate'd
09-17 14:11:25.101: D/ApacheBtService(4552): state: connecting
09-17 14:11:25.111: D/MetaWatchReminderApp(4552): getBluetoothMac D0:37:61:C3:34:B5
09-17 14:11:25.151: D/BluetoothSocket(4552): create BluetoothSocket: type = 1, fd = -1, uuid = [00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb], port = -1
09-17 14:11:25.261: D/ApacheBtService(4552): before connect
```

The service is running and then something call the function the OnCreate method, but it does not call the OnStartCommand function, does any have any ideas why that happent?

Answer (score 0):

See flags which you may return in `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)`. If Android restarts your service call `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)` not guaranteed for some flags.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: It was also my first suspicion, but when a service is killed should it first call onDestroy then call OnCreated agian?

Comment: OnCreated calls only if you service not started yet. I think, that Android may close your service without calling onDestroy if another app need more memory.

Comment: Thank you, I thougth that OnDestroy was called if a service was killed. Maybe a link where I can read a bit more about this? Should I override OnLowMemory function and make some cleanup there?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle